# Solr - Wild Card Search varies with Stemming Methods

Tags: solr, wildcard, stemming

I have 2 versions of solr working in my machine . say `SolrVer1` and `SolrVer2`

`SolrVer1` have applied , below stemming methods on field type `text_en_splitting`

```
<filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
 <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"/>
```

`SolrVer2` have applied , below stemming methods on field type `text_en_splitting`

```
<filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
```

it works almost same for regular search , but while using wild card search then wild card search does not giving results with grammatical on  `SolrVer1`

like searching with  `ray*` , `SolrVer1` returns very less data as compared to `SolrVer2`. when i observed the results then i found that `SolrVer1` does not return data with only `ray` and `rays`.

I don't know where i should use `SnowballPorterFilterFactory` and where i should use `PorterStemFilterFactory` . and what are the pros and cons of them?

Can anybody have idea on this behavior ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to know what the stemmers output for `ray`, `rays`.

Try stemming them at the Porter stemmer online tool: http://qaa.ath.cx/porter_js_demo.html. It outputs `rai`! That's the reason you don't get any matches for `ray*` with Porter stemmer.

And here is a tool for snowball stemmer: http://snowball.tartarus.org/demo.php.
This outputs `ray` for `ray` and `rays` which is why you get the results.

You may want to read this for comparing the two stemmers: http://snowball.tartarus.org/texts/introduction.html

Appears like snowball was designed to address such short-comings of Porter.

Comment: Thanks @arun , for your reply. its really very helpful. so do you suggest that i should use `SnowballPorterFilterFactory` ?

Comment: In general, snowball (including Porter) stemmers are considered aggressive, meaning they will map a lot of words to the same stem.  It is tough to tell which stemmer you should use, since it depends on your search needs. I would recommend asking your customers for examples. You should read  https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Stemming to understand the differences between various Solr stemmers and pick the correct one for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @arun for your reply , i guess you are right, I'll ask my customer for examples. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Analyzers](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Analyzers)

```
On wildcard and fuzzy searches, no text analysis is performed on the search word.
```

As no analysis is done at query time for wilcard searches and hence the stemmers would be applied during query time.
The results would be different depending upon what the stemmers are producing.

Comment: Thanks @Jayendra, for your reply. yes i seen that for wild card search results differ depending upon stemmer applied on them.